# How To Create a Custom Mount Function

Tags: cypress

Im trying to make a custom mount function to mount my own custom components but the example i found is no longer working.

The example i tried is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/mount-utils#user-content-example-mount-adapter-web-components

It seems that ROOT_SELECTOR does not match to anything anymore? Is this code perhaps outdated?

Does anyone know how to do something like this on the latest cypress version?

Comment: The [first line of the source code](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/npm/mount-utils/src/index.ts) has the ROOT_SELECTOR: `export const ROOT_SELECTOR = '[data-cy-root]'` What are you doing to break it?

Comment: The const is returning something but the page does not have that selector in it any place.